# Excel rounds up 10/3 * 3 to 10, how to keep the 9.99?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically what is says on the title. I've tried moving the decimal place further with no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're canceling out the operation `(1/3)*3 == 1` .. that's the same as saying `10-3+3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not rounding up; 10 / 3 * 3 is exactly 10, not 9.99. You're asking for Excel to lie to you, and so you're not going to have any luck.

Comment: Oh haha, good point, can't believe I missed that. I guess I'll just make it 3.333333 then.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to lose the precision (as stated above, 10/3*3 is exactly 10), use the `round` function:

```
=ROUND(10/3,2)*3
```